# List with 2 elements, a list and an int, want to relate every list item with that int

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists in which every element of the first list is composed of a second list and an integer.

What I want to do is relate that single integer with every element in the list, thus making the elements of the first list be lists of 2 elements the code. I haven't got a clue on how to do this.

This is the code i'm using to test this:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]


list2 = []
list3 = []

for element in range (len(list1)):
    list2.append(list1[element][0])
    list2.append(list3)
    list3.append([list1[element][1:]])
    list3[element].append(list1[element][0])    

print(list3)
```

Comment: Please post the actual code, and do not name variables things like `list`, `set`, `dict`,...

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do here. Perhaps an example wouldn't be such a bad idea?

Comment: Ok thanks, i have list = [1,[2,3]] and i want it to be list = [[1,2],[1,3]] i renamed them like that out of fast translation sorry

Comment: Can you show the desired output for the `list1` you used in the question? It’s unclear how your example should expand onto sublists with more than two elements. And also, where that single int is coming from.

Comment: The idea is to create a function that given any list of lists:                      1.takes out the first element of every sub-list and creates another sub-list with that single item and the remaining list( Example : [[1,2,3]] => [1,[2,3]]        2. converts the new sub-lists in to several sub-lists relating all of the elements of the remaining list with that single item.(Example : [1,[2,3]] => [[[1,2],[1,3]]])

Comment: what i have so far is the conversion from list1 to list 3 where the output is shown on the shell bellow the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach for your first example:

```
l = [1,[2,3]] 
final_l = [[l[0], i] for i in l[-1]]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

A solution for a larger example:

```
l = [[1,[2,3]], [3, [45, 2]], [6, [12, 2]], [3, [3, 4]]]
final_l = [[[c, a] for c in b] for a, b in l]
```

Output:

```
[[[2, 1], [3, 1]], [[45, 3], [2, 3]], [[12, 6], [2, 6]], [[3, 3], [4, 3]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list2 = [[[l[0], num] for num in l[1:]] for l in list1]
```

The output is:

```
list2 = [[[1, 2], [1, 3]], [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Another question, would this also work with string elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can try in one line with this approach:

```
l = [[1,[2,3]], [3, [45, 2]], [6, [12, 2]], [3, [3, 4]]]

print(list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda y:[y,x[0]],x[1])),l)))
```

output:

```
[[[2, 1], [3, 1]], [[45, 3], [2, 3]], [[12, 6], [2, 6]], [[3, 3], [4, 3]]]
```